# During installation of Ubuntu 12.04.3 on 2 year-old Toshiba Satellite, graphics fails

Tags: 12.04, system-installation, ssd, toshiba-satellite

I recently upgraded to an SSD on a 2-year old Toshiba Satellite laptop.

On this laptop, I had previously installed 12.04 LTS, and it installed like a charm.  I had tried other Linux flavors, but came back to Ubuntu as my favorite, so I had installed 12.04 LTS at least three times, and each time it had installed quickly and beautifully (selling me on Linux - loved it).

However now with the new SSD (which works well with Windows), when I ran the original 12.04 disc that I usually use for installs, and it hung.

So I downloaded the latest version 12.04.3 and during the install (I've made several attempts) the graphics will fail, preventing an installation.

Below are the specs.  Any advice?  Love Ubuntu and would love to get it back on my

Satellite C655D-S5300 Laptop

```
AMD E-Series Processor E-300
Windows 7 Home Premium (64-bit), SP1
4GB DDR3 memory
AMD® Integrated Graphics
320GB HDD (5400rpm, Serial ATA) (replaced with a Kingston 120GB SSD)
DVD-SuperMulti drive (+/-R double layer)
Wi-Fi® Wireless networking (802.11b/g/n)
No Bluetooth (No Antenna)
Standard US keyboard with 10-key pad (Black)
Touch pad pointing device with multi touch control
Li-Ion (48Wh, 6-Cell)
2-USB (2.0) ports
```

Comment: did you check the md5 of the 12.04.3 iso you downloaded?

Comment: try to use newer ubuntu - 13.10 or 14.04. The 12.04.03 is a bit old now :)